# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './App' at webpackMissingModule

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I'm receiving the error `Uncaught Error: Module not found: Can't resolve ./App' and ./store in  client/src.` in the console of the local environment when I run `npm start` from the client directory.

The screen renders 2 errors.

- `ERROR in ./src/index.tsx 7:0-24 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './App.tsx' in '/client/src'`
- `ERROR in ./src/index.tsx 7:0-24 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './store.ts' in '/client/src'`

However, when I import the client directory of my project into a CodeSandbox, it is working.

`client/src/index`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import persistStore from 'redux-persist/es/persistStore';
import setupStore from './store';

const store = setupStore();
const persistor = persistStore(store);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
            <App />
        </PersistGate>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Solution Attempts:

- delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, then `npm install`
- `npm cache clean --force` and `npm cache clear --force`
- assured the dependencies and packages installed in my local environment are the same in CodeSandbox.
- Made sure that the App component and the store module actually exist in the src/ directory.
- Checked that the file name for both App and store is spelled correctly and that the file extension is correct as well (e.g., .tsx for React components).
- assured `file paths` are correct
- using Chrome on both local and CodeSandbox

What's going on?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem you mentioned in the CodeSandbox. In it however is a TypeScript error that tells you about a missing config in the tsconfig.json: `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` is required to import React and ReactDOM the way you did. After that, the Sandbox renders fine for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-star-52srdv

Comment: @geisterfurz007 Hey there, thanks for the help. The sandbox was originally working actually. It is my local environment that I'm having issues with. I've provided the link to the GitHub repo (located at the bottom of the question) if you'd like to clone it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you started with a `JavaScript` project generated by [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/) and then you tried to migrate the project to `TypeScript`.

When you make this migration, the Create React App scripts are supposed to automatically generate a `tsconfig.json` file as soon as you rename any of your `*.js` files to `*.ts`. However, it seems that currently there is an [issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10951#issuecomment-839711690) and the `tsconfig.json` file is NOT automatically generated - this is the root cause for the error you see.

The workaround is simple: generate the `tsconfig.json` file manually. You can see an example file generated by Create React App when it actually works here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10951#issuecomment-839711690.

Comment: Thank you for attempted solution. I pasted the default setup of `tsconfig.json` but unfortunately, the error persist. Did you by chance get it to work with the provided repo?

Comment: Yep, I did - I downloaded your repo, verified the error you were getting (i.e. I got the same error when I tried to run ```npm run start``` or ```npm run build```), then added ```tsconfig.json``` from the linked issue, re-run ```npm run build``` and the error was gone. Where did you place the ```tsconfig.json``` file? It should be in the ```client``` directory, NOT in the root directory.

Comment: It worked! My mistake was that I placed the `tsconfig.json` file in the root directory. I appreciate your help!